# How to fix "MaxDepth exceeded" error in Bot Composer?

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I am building a bot using Bot Composer, and I am encountering the following error:

```
"The reader’s MaxDepth of 64 has been exceeded. Path ‘DialogState.dialogStack.$values[0].state._adaptive.actions.$values[0].dialogStack.$values[0].state[‘this.actionScopeState’].dialogStack.$values[0].state._adaptive.actions.$values[0].dialogStack.$values[0].state._adaptive.actions.$values[0].dialogStack.$values[0].state._adaptive.actions.$values[0].dialogStack.$values[0].state._adaptive.actions.$values[0].dialogStack.$values[0].state._adaptive.actions.$values[0].dialogStack.$values’."
```

I am not sure what is causing this error or how to fix it.
Can someone please help me understand what is happening and how I can resolve this issue?
I have tried simplifying my conversation flow and refactoring my code,
but I am still encountering the same error.

Any help or guidance on this issue would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance!

Typically used to gather more information about a specific problem or error that someone is encountering.

"I have tried simplifying my conversation flow and refactoring my code to remove any unnecessary complexity.
I was expecting these changes to resolve the "MaxDepth exceeded" error, but I am still encountering the same issue.

I also looked online for any solutions or guidance on how to fix this error, but I was not able to find anything that resolved my problem."

By providing this information, you are giving context to your problem and explaining what steps you have taken so far to try and resolve it.

This can help others better understand your situation and provide more targeted advice or suggestions for how to fix the issue.

Comment: Properly end your dialog after each process otherwise the stack will create this kind of exception. If the active stack will increase more than 8 dialogs then this kind of issue is occurring in the bot flow.